How can i implement Transcribe audio from stream audio through django WebSocket by google-speech-to-text API
I tried to implement this, but transcripts are not generating. implemented backend code below.
class ReadingConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        credentials = "my_google_credential"
        self.client = speech.SpeechClient(credentials=credentials)

        self.config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
            sample_rate_hertz=16000,
            language_code="en-US",
        )
        self.streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=self.config,
            interim_results=True
        )
        self.closed = False
        self.audio_chunks = asyncio.Queue()
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        #self.audio_chunks = queue.Queue()
        self.transcription_thread = None
        self.transcription_started = False
        #self.audio_queue = queue.Queue()
        print("Streaming task started")


    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print(f"WebSocket disconnected with code: {close_code}")
        self.closed = True
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        if self.transcription_thread and self.transcription_thread.is_alive():
            self.audio_chunks.put(None)  # Signal to stop transcription
            self.transcription_thread.join()

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        if bytes_data:
            print(f"Received bytes data size: {len(bytes_data)}")
            await self.audio_chunks.put(bytes_data)
            print(f'audio chunk initial queue: {self.audio_chunks.qsize()}')
            #self.streaming_task.send(bytes_data)
            if not self.transcription_started:
                print('Thread run')
                self.transcription_started = True
                self.transcription_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.stream_audio)
                self.transcription_thread.start()
            
    def sync_audio_stream_generator(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        while not self.closed:
            #chunk = loop.run_until_complete(self.fetch_audio_data())#self.audio_chunks.get()
            #if chunk is None:
            #    return
            #data = [chunk]
            #while True:
            try:
                # Get the next chunk from the queue
                print(f"Synchronous generator yielding: {self.audio_chunks.qsize()}")
                chunk = loop.run_until_complete(self.fetch_audio_data())#self.audio_chunks.get(block=False)
                #chunk = self.audio_chunks.get()#block=False
                if chunk is None:
                    print("No more audio chunks. Stopping the generator.")
                    return
                print(f'inside generator data returned')
                yield chunk
            except queue.Empty:
                print("Queue is empty, break")
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'exception sync_audio_stream_generator: {e}')
                break
            #yield b"".join(data)
    async def fetch_audio_data(self):
        """
        Asynchronous helper function to fetch data from the queue.
        This runs inside the sync generator using the event loop.
        """
        try:
            # Wait for audio data to be put in the queue, timeout after 1 second
            return await asyncio.wait_for(self.audio_chunks.get(), timeout=1)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            # If no data, return None to keep the transcription stream going
            return None
    def stream_audio(self):
        print("Starting audio streaming to Google Speech-to-Text API")
        try:
            audio_generator = self.sync_audio_stream_generator()
            print(f"generator: {audio_generator}")
            #time.sleep(2)
            #await asyncio.sleep(1)
            requests = (speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content) for content in audio_generator)
            print(f'requests: {requests}')
            #time.sleep(2)
            responses = self.client.streaming_recognize(self.streaming_config, requests)
            print(f'responses: {responses}')

            for response in responses:
                print(f'response results: {response}')
                if not response.results:
                    continue
                result = response.results[0]
                if not result.alternatives:
                    continue

                # Display the transcription of the top alternative.
                transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript
                #await self.compare_and_send_word_by_word(transcript)
                print(f'transcript: {transcript}')
                asyncio.run(self.send_transcript(transcript))

            print('last line')
        except Exception as e:
            #traceback.print_exc()
            print(f"Error in stream_audio: {str(e)}")
            traceback.print_exc()
    async def send_transcript(self, transcript):
        # Send the transcript back to the WebSocket client asynchronously
        #await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"transcription": "hello....", "is_final": True}))
        await self.send(text_data=transcript)

frontend implementation code also given below. Frontend code captured 1 channel mono audio as requirment of google stt.
document.getElementById('startBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: {
                    deviceId: "default",
                    channelCount: 1,   // Mono audio
                    sampleRate: 16000, // 16 kHz sampleRate  :{ideal: 16000}
                    sampleSize: 16,
                } }).then((stream) => {
                    if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm'))
                        return alert('Browser not supported')

                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
                        mimeType: 'audio/webm',
                    })

                    socket = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8000/ws/transcribe/${chapterId}/`);

                    socket.onopen = () => {
                        document.querySelector('#status').textContent = 'Connected'
                        console.log({ event: 'onopen' })

                        mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', async (event) => {
                            if (event.data.size > 0 && socket.readyState == 1) {
                                socket.send(event.data)
                            }
                        })
                        mediaRecorder.start(250)
})})

What is the actual issue of the above code, and please someone give me the actual implementation. I debug the code, and did not get any exception ar error. code is running perfectily and receiving audio chunk continously. I used threading because while executing the code websocket block for some times and it cause of google timeout error. streaming_recognize expects continous audio chunk and wait for maximum 4 seconds.
